# scalable web application with redis

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redis

we are building a web application, multiple dashboards and reports, that uses multiple datasources to read the data

we are planning to use redis cache to make performance better of the application

what should be the better solution for this

1) loading data periodically into the redis cache and serve it from the cache

this seems very good at first but has problem that for dashboards and reports that are not frequently used we will be pulling the data after the certain time hence creating unnecessary load on application and cache

2) not loading the data into the cache will take minutes of time to load for one dashboard or report

what should be the ideal approach we can take in such system where number of users are very much likely to expand to tens of thousand in a year after the release

we are using java, spring, hibernate, and redis cache on server side and angular2 on client side